# html.TextBoxFor formatting for numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can I use number format in html.TextBoxFor

I want to use number format 1.01 or 02.01 or 02.1 meaning (x.xx) or (xx.xx) or (xx.x) and numbers are limited (0 to 9)

Comment: Automatic formatting requires a JavaScript solution. Just do a search. You'll literally find hundreds of options.

Comment: Perhaps a `[Regex]` attribute on the property

Answer (score 0):

try adding number type and step properties,

```
@html.TextBoxFor(...., new {type="number", step="0.01"})
```

Comment: step will not work because input could be anything between 0 to 9 , 1.02 or 5.67 or 09.13

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Also set the min and max attribute to zero and nine of the html textbox.

```
var Validation = function (v) {
var regex = /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/;
return v.match(regex);
}
```